# Error compiling Ejabberd dependency of a Phoenix application with Mix: could not compile dependency :ejabberd, "mix compile" failed

Tags: erlang, elixir, ejabberd, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I have been trying to embed [Ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) into a [Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/) web application. To do this, I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://blog.process-one.net/embedding-ejabberd-into-an-elixir-phoenix-web-application/). The steps were the following:

- Installed a [ubuntu/xenial64](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64) [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/) box.
- Installed Elixir according to the [official guide](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like).
- Installed Phoenix according to the [official guide](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/installation).
- Installed some packages to successfully compile the Phoenix' seed app dependencies: `sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-cpp-dev libyaml-dev libpython2.7-dev`
- I've added the `ejabberd` dependency to the `mix.exs` file:

  ```
  defmodule PhoenixEjabberd.Mixfile do
    use Mix.Project

    def project do
      [app: :phoenix_ejabberd,
       version: "0.0.1",
       elixir: "~> 1.2",
       elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
       compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
       build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
       start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
       aliases: aliases(),
       deps: deps()]
    end

    # Configuration for the OTP application.
    #
    # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
    def application do
      [mod: {PhoenixEjabberd, []},
       applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, 
                      :logger, :ejabberd, :gettext,
                      :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex]]
    end

    # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
    defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
    defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]

    # Specifies your project dependencies.
    #
    # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
    defp deps do
      [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
       {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
       {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
       {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
       {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
       {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
       {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
       {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
       {:ejabberd, "~> 16.12", github: "processone/ejabberd"}
     ]
    end

    # Aliases are shortcuts or tasks specific to the current project.
    # For example, to create, migrate and run the seeds file at once:
    #
    #     $ mix ecto.setup
    #
    # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
    defp aliases do
      ["ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
       "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
       "test": ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]]
    end
  end
  ```
- Executed `mix do deps.get, compile`
- Got a very large amount of errors, mostly of undefined functions and variables. I put the full log on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/marcusmonteiro/3c50586bc72dec6cfb79aadf2e707e7c).

Why are those errors occurring? Did anyone succeed in compiling the `ejabberd` dependency? How? Thank you for your time :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unknown reason `ejabberd` fails to compile from the root project folder. To compile it, I did the following:

```
mix deps.get # to retrieve ejabberd 
cd deps/ejabberd
mix do deps.get, compile
cd - # to the project root
mix compile # now the project would compile
```